# Lua Unix Timestamp to a date

Tags: lua

I have a unix timestamp coming from my mysql database, and I wanna convert it to a date, but when I try to use

```
local time = 1647385200000
os.date("%Y %m %d", time)
```

It just returns nil, and I don't really understand why, when I look at documentation it seems like it should be able to take a unix timestamp and give me a date, but idk

Thanks,
Ossie

Comment: You should convert milliseconds to seconds before passing time to `os.date`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff how would I convert it?

Comment: Divide by 1000 :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `math.ceil(time / 1e3)`?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 1):

First: The time is...

```
time = os.date("%H:%M:%S", os.time())
```

You can get current date/time in epoch...

```
epoch = os.time()
```

...and the epoch of a individual date/time with...

```
epoch = os.time({year = 2022, month = 3, day = 9, hour = 13, min = 10, sec = 45})
```

After that you can do your format with...

```
os.date("%Y %m %d", epoch)
```

@OssieFromDK - Look what os.time() returns...

```
> print(os.time())
1646837380
> print(os.time({year = 2022, month = 3, day = 9, hour = 13, min = 10, sec = 45}))
1646827845
```

You see? - Epoch without milliseconds has currently 10 digits.
( Can be 0 and also negativ for birthday/history dates before 1970 )
Also the errormessage from os.date() tells me...

```
> os.date(_, 1647385200000)
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'date' (time out-of-bounds)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'os.date'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

...that the number is not in known range of os.date()

A simple and safer way in your case to cut down to 10 digits is...

```
> time = 1647385200000
-- Next convert and cut down even if time is a float/integer/string
> print(os.date(_, tostring(time):sub(1, 10)))
Wed Mar 16 00:00:00 2022
```

...os.date() fortunately accepts a string.
When it can be translated to an integer (Autoconversion by Lua).

Simple dividing could lead to a float number and os.date() dont accept that...

```
> time = 1647385200123 / 1000
> print(os.date(_, time))
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'date' (number has no integer representation)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'os.date'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
> print(math.type(time))
float
> print(time)
1647385200.123
```

( All above is done in an interactive Lua console - Should work from 5.1 upwards )

Comment: Well, how would I get the epoch of a unix timestamp? Its not a table, but a number